# MySQL - Select where all rows sharing the same id, each contain a column equal to null

Tags: mysql, sql

Bit tricky trying to word this one, I'll start by giving an example

Table name: tags

```
artist_id(int) | tag_id(int) | main_tag(NULL by default)
```

The rows can contain multiple different tags for each artist and one of them needs to be set as a main tag.

So I'm trying to find out all the artists that do not currently have a main tag set in one of the rows.

Example:

```
artist_id | tag_id | main_tag
 2203         4         NULL
 2203         53         1
 2203         32        NULL
```

I don't want to retrieve the artist id here as a main tag has been set for this artist.

Whereas:

```
artist_id | tag_id | main_tag
 1333         23       NULL
 1333         44       NULL
```

I want to get this artist_id as all the main_tag values are NULL.

I'm stuck on how to put this into an SQL statement, will really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So lets break this down:

The artists you want to ignore are returned by the following query:

```
SELECT artist_id 
FROM   tags 
WHERE  main_tag IS NOT NULL
```

So the ones you DO want are the ones where the artist_id is not in the above list:

```
SELECT artist_id, 
       tag_id 
FROM   tags 
WHERE  artist_id NOT IN (SELECT artist_id 
                         FROM   tags 
                         WHERE  main_tag IS NOT NULL);
```

If you want just the artist_id, and you want each artist to appear only once, then you can remove the reference to tag_id, and group them by artist:

```
SELECT artist_id 
FROM   tags 
WHERE  artist_id NOT IN (SELECT artist_id 
                         FROM   tags 
                         WHERE  main_tag IS NOT NULL) 
GROUP  BY artist_id;
```

Hint: if you want to post something database-ish, you can build your tables in sqlfiddle, then post the link, which gives people a starting point. I did this, the link is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db53d/2

Answer (score 0):

Following queries produce as same as @AMADNON Inc.'s query result.

**A. GROUP BY and HAVING**

```
SELECT artist_id
FROM tags
GROUP BY artist_id
HAVING SUM(main_tag IS NULL) = COUNT(*);
```

**B. INNER JOIN**

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.artist_id
FROM tags t1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT artist_id 
    FROM tags WHERE main_tag IS NOT NULL
  ) t2 ON t1.artist_id != t2.artist_id;
```

**C. NOT EXISTS**

```
SELECT DISTINCT artist_id
FROM tags t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM tags
    WHERE main_tag IS NOT NULL 
        AND artist_id = t1.artist_id
);
```

It would be much better if you let me know the performance results for each queries if you have a lot of data.